# createdb with newly created postgres user

Tags: postgresql

Created the following postgres user:

```
   rolname   | rolsuper | rolinherit | rolcreaterole | rolcreatedb | rolcatupdate | rolcanlogin | rolreplication | rolconnlimit | rolpassword | rolvaliduntil | rolconfig |  oid  
-------------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+-------
 myuser | f        | t          | f             | t           | f            | t           | f              |           -1 | ********    |               |           | 24577
```

Then did this:

```
alter user myuser with unencrypted password 'asdf';
```

And then I tried to create a database:

```
createdb -U myuser -W mydb
```

I entered the password 'asdf', but then get this:

```
createdb: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "myuser"
```

This user has rolcreatedb privileges, so why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command specified `with encrypted password 'asdf';`   The cleartext password that encrypts to `asdf` will not be `asdf`.   You need to either specife `with unencrypted password` or calculate the encrypted value.   The `\password` command in psql is better to use.

Also, you need to specify in your `pg_hba.conf` file that password authentication is allowed;  the default is (I believe) to only authenticate you as your unix user unless you are the superuser.

Comment: I just ran "alter user myuser with unencrypted password 'asdf';" and then ran "createdb -U myuser -W mydb", same error.  I will update the question.

Comment: Edited.  Is password (or md5) authentication allowed in your `pg_hba.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

Check your **pg_hba.conf** file and look for the following line:

`local   all             all                                     trust`

At the end of the file you can try to change from **trust** to **md5**, after that you must reload the service. Here goes a explanation from pg_hba.conf:

> METHOD can be "trust", "reject", "md5", "password", "gss", "sspi",
>   "ident", "peer", "pam", "ldap", "radius" or "cert".  Note that
>   "password" sends passwords in clear text; "md5" is preferred since
>   it sends encrypted passwords.

More information about new users you can find at:
https://wiki.debian.org/PostgreSql#New_User_and_database